# What are the parameters to select contour in Residue theorem? How we reject and accept the residues?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

can someone offer a clear conceptual treatment of contour consideration in residue theorem? How can I judge which residues to accept and which to reject when the limits of the integral is from -infinity to +infinity?

[For example, an integration is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqgAX.jpg)

d21 = (-kp v + delta_p + i gamma_21)

d31 = (-kp v - kc v + (delta_p + delta_c) + i gamma_31)

and the function in the integral is: f(v)=vT/((v^2+vT^2)pi^1/2)

Could anybody help out solving this integral for v.

Comment: If you have a closed path in the complex plane, you can apply residue theorem to all the singularities inside the path.

Comment: I have come across some problems in which the author has selected some of the residues inside the closed path and rejected other residues inside the same closed path. That's why I want to know the concepts behind the contour and residue consideration.

Comment: I don't know why they would reject some residues, all of them inside the contour must be ustilized in residue theorem.

Comment: @aleden I have edited the question now. Hope you get something from it.
Thanx for helping out

Answer (score 0):

The following statement isn't quite precise enough for universal application, but can be useful:  Singularities to the left of a person following the path of integration are included, singularities to the right are excluded.  For a person walking along the real axis from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, there is no ambiguity: the singularities in the upper half plane are on the left and the singularities in the lower half plane are on the right.  Se we keep the singularities in the upper half plane.  (If the singularity lies on the path, there are a variety of ways to proceed -- more detail would be needed.)

Comment: please refer to the letter https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAB.31.000704 for the integral problem (equation 7).
The author selected the singularity on the lower half plane and rejected the singularities on the upper half plane. This is in contrary to the method you suggested.